# Cannot show the original picture use opencv-python 3.4

Tags: python, opencv

I'am a newer for opencv. 
I used the next command install the opencv 3.4

```
 py -3 -m pip install open_python-3.4.4.19-cp36-cp36m-win_ame64.whl
```

and use the code named Image_Thresholding.ipynb process the picture 
the file Image_Thresholding.ipynb like this:

```
 import cv2
 pic = cv2.imread('adult.jpg', 0)
 threshold_value = 200
 (T_value, binary_threshold) = cv2.threshold(pic, threshold_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
 cv2.imshow('binary', binary_threshold)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I used pycharm2018.3.1 and set the configurations to use  Jupter Notebook to run up code show the processed the picture, It's a  white and black picture but I want use the next code
to show the original picture  it also show the processed white and black picture

```
 import cv2
 img = cv2.imread('adult.jpg', 0)
 cv2.imshow('adult', img)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

How to show the original picture. Is  my environment wrong or any else problem ?

Comment: I used next command to uninstal the opencv-python-3.4.4.19  and  install the opencv-python-3.4.5.20  not chang  any thing

Comment: my code did not show the original picture  It only show the  the processed two region  picture , I mean to show the original picture like grey picture

Comment: I mean to show the grayscale picture of the original picture  so I used 0,  but is also show the processed thresholding picture, The  pycharm like  has memory function ,It did not show the original picture.

Comment: And I changed another file Natural.jpg it has not processed use the cv2.threshold function , It show the original  picture but only up right corner of the original picture,How do I show the whole picture

Comment: I used the sentence  cv2.imshow('adult', pic)  to change the cv2.imshow('binary', binary_threshold)  sentence    it did not show the original greyscale  picture , is my environment wrong  but I  used matplotlib   pyplot   plt.show is show correctly, why

Comment: It like my environment  is wrong , how do I install the opencv-python environment

Comment: I only install the vc_redist.x64.exe  visual C++ redistributable for visual studio 2015,

Comment: And  used the command py -3 -m pip install  opencv_python-3.4.5.20-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl  to install the opencv environment  Is it correct?

Comment: Hello @maryadi, I posted an answer to your question, did you read it?

Comment: Yes , I read it, and it not the problem , it not like simple as that  I used pyplot  and plt.show  can show the correct  picture

Comment: Is opencv has rewrite property  the binary_threshold has rewrite to the pic pictures

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing such issue because of the `0` flag you use in the `imread` function call. That is used to read images in grayscale.

In order to load and display a color image just do:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('adult.jpg')
cv2.imshow('adult', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: But my  cv2.imshow('adult', img)  didn't  show the picture and  show the two binary threshold picture  and the threshold picture is not correct. I used pyplot plt.show It show the correct two binary threshold pictures

Comment: I used another picture and it get the right  threshold. I think is the image I used has problems.